# Can't reach an internal IP from the outside world using iptables NAT

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have 2 VM's, one is acting as a router and an Ubuntu server and is connected to the host via a bridged connection and the other one is a Kali machine that is connected to the server VM via a host only connection.

The Kali machine has an IP of 192.168.0.40 and the server has an IP of 172.16.23.100.

The iptables rules i have set are this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 114 packets, 20912 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       all  --  ens33  *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.23.101        to:192.168.0.40

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 8700 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 422 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 422 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   168 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens33   192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      ens33   192.168.0.40         0.0.0.0/0            to:172.16.23.101
```

going from the Kali machine outside to the host works fine, but when i try to go from the host to the Kali machine either by simple ping or with ssh it doesn't go through.

Do i need to set DNAT to work with only a specific port?

The file generated by iptables-save as per the request of @grawity

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Jul 27 06:58:13 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [686:75420]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [485:45172]
-A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 27 06:58:13 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Thu Jul 27 06:58:13 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:240]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:240]
-A PREROUTING -d 172.16.23.101/32 -i ens33 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.40
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.40/32 -o ens33 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.23.101
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul 27 06:58:13 2017
```

When i run a tcpdump on the router/server it shows me that it's sending arp requests to the 172.16.23.101 address but nothing is getting sent back, i don't really understand why it isn't caught in the NAT rule if it's in the PREROUTING chain

Comment: Could you show the real rules, as in `iptables-save`?

Comment: @grawity added it to the main post

Comment: Normally I'd have a rule in the input chain, allowing access to a specific port...

Comment: Does the host's physical network interface receive the packets sent to `172.16.23.101`? Probably the problem is not on iptable's side, but on the interface's side, which doesn't know it has to receive these packets. What you say about ARP being not responded to seems to confirm that.

Comment: @NathanShiraini I assumed the problem wasn't with iptables, but how do i make the interface receive these packets? i would assume it's just make ipv4 routing possible, but i already did that. so what am i missing?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/547300/600828  -- whatever solution you choose, may sure to test it first! I don't have anything to test this right now, and messing with interfaces can be somewhat dangerous (especially if you don't have local access to your server).

Answer (score 2):

The problem wasn't the iptables rules, those were fine. but when trying to get to 172.16.23.101 it sent arp requests to see who has that address, which was no one.

so i added a sub interface to ens33 and gave it that address

i added to the '/etc/network/interfaces' file these line

```
auto ens33:1
iface ens33:1 inet static
    address 172.16.23.101
    netmask 255.255.0.0
```

then if i ping 172.16.23.101 with tcpdump running on the server i can see that the ttl is 63 which means it went through one layer 3 equipment, because the default ttl for linux is 64